# Adding two or more arrays with similar values together into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, merge

I've got an array, that contains 100 arrays that each 3160 values of  an object with two values, one is a sequence number(I think the number only appears if there is a 1 present), and the other is either a 0 or a 1.

I want to combine all 100 arrays into one array with 3160 values of an object with two values, a list of all the sequence numbers contained in all 100 arrays, and a total value of all of the 0s and 1s summed up.

I've tried concatenate but I don't want more than 3160 entries

```
/*results of what I have
  Array(100)
    [0]Array(3160)
      [0]: Seq: 12345
           fq: 1
      [1]: Seq: 12345
           fq: 0
      [2]: Seq: 12345
           fq: 1
      [3]: Seq: 12345
           fq: 0
      and so on...
    [1]Array(3160)
      [0]: Seq: 12346
           fq: 1
      [1]: Seq: 12346
           fq: 1
      [2]: Seq: 12346
           fq: 0
      [3]: Seq: 12346
           fq: 0
      and so on...
    [2]Array(3160)
      [0]: Seq: 12347
           fq: 1
      [1]: Seq: 12347
           fq: 0
      [2]: Seq: 12347
           fq: 1
      [3]: Seq: 12347
           fq: 0
      and so on...
    and so on...


What I Want:
    Array(3160)
      [0]: Seq: 12345, 12346, 12347
           fq: 3
      [1]: Seq: 12346
           fq: 1
      [2]: Seq: 12345, 12347
           fq: 2
      [3]: Seq: 
           fq: 0
*/
```

Comment: please add some data who match the wanted result or vice versa. please add the data in literal notation (like you get by using `JSON.stringify`)

Comment: if you scrolldown in the code, it shows how I want them to add together

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm extremely new to coding, I don't know what the literal notation would be, I just want to end up with an array of whatever name that adds the first 100 values into one array of the totals. I'm just using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok given your comments I guess you are looking for something like this :

```js
let array = [[{Seq: 12345, fq: 1}, {Seq: 12345, fq: 0}],
             [{Seq: 12346, fq: 1}, {Seq: 12346, fq: 1}],
             [{Seq: 12346, fq: 1}, {Seq: 12346, fq: 1}],
             [{Seq: 12347, fq: 1}, {Seq: 12347, fq: 0}]];

let output = new Array();
             

array.forEach(entrie => entrie.forEach((obj, index) => {
  if(obj.fq) {
    output[index] = output[index] || {Seq: [], fq: 0};
    if(!output[index].Seq.includes(obj.Seq)) output[index].Seq.push(obj.Seq);
    output[index].fq += obj.fq;
  }
}));

console.log(output);
```

Since it's a bit different than what you described into your question, i prefer to create a new answer than editing the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [[{Seq: 12345, fq: 1}, {Seq: 12345, fq: 0}],
             [{Seq: 12346, fq: 1}, {Seq: 12346, fq: 1}],
             [{Seq: 12347, fq: 1}, {Seq: 12347, fq: 0}]];

let output = new Array();
             

array.forEach(entrie => entrie.forEach((obj, index) => {
  if(obj.fq) {
    output[index] = output[index] || {Seq: [], fq: 0};
    output[index].Seq.push(obj.Seq);
    output[index].fq += obj.fq;
  }
}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Awesome, this one works awesome, but is there any way to get the Sequence numbers to store as an array of numbers instead of a string?

Comment: Oh, damn. This one is getting the right frequency but it's only storing the most recent sequence number, just noticed. I dont yet know if its this code or my code

Comment: Right, so my massive array does record all the right numbers but after running your reduction code, the frequency is correct, but your code just copies the most recent sequence number repeatedly instead of recording the full list of sequences where a 1 occurs

Comment: I edited my answer to create an array instead of a string, but if you only get the last sequence value repeatedly, it means your array is wrong since, as you can see by running this example, the output is right given your expected result

Answer (score -1):

You could iterate the array and build new items on the same index as the given inner arrays.

```js
var data = [[{ Seq: 12345, fq: 1 }, { Seq: 12345, fq: 0 }, { Seq: 12345, fq: 1 }, { Seq: 12345, fq: 0 }], [{ Seq: 12346, fq: 1 }, { Seq: 12346, fq: 1 }, { Seq: 12346, fq: 0 }, { Seq: 12346, fq: 0 }], [{ Seq: 12347, fq: 1 }, { Seq: 12347, fq: 0 }, { Seq: 12347, fq: 1 }, { Seq: 12347, fq: 0 }]],
    result = data.reduce((r, a) => {
        a.forEach(({ Seq, fq }, i) => {
            if (!fq) return;
            r[i] = r[i] || { Seq: [], fq: 0 };
            r[i].Seq.push(Seq);
            r[i].fq++;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I will try this in the am, heading to bed now

Comment: Should not `r[i].fq++;` be `r[i].fq+=fq;` ?

Comment: @PopHip, could be, but *"... is either a 0 or a 1 ..."*.

Comment: When I ran this one it told me a.forEach isn't a function

Comment: is `a` an array?

Comment: I haven't used a for anything previously besides where it shows in your code

Comment: do you have double nested arrays, as in data?

Comment: Okay, I see what I did wrong, but it's now giving me the same problem as the other line of code below. Instead of recording the list of sequence numbers that record a 1, it just repeats the most recent sequence number as many times as it should occur in that list

Comment: {…}
​​​
Seq: "2437863, 2437863, 2437863, 2437863"
​​​
fq: 4

Comment: what do you want in this case?

Comment: Also, it's returning those numbers as a string, but I was hoping to return an array of integers

Comment: it's the same as you have in the question. but no problem.

Comment: In the above paste, it should be returning different Seq numbers, because that combination (1 & 2) didn't come up in that sequence, it was on different sequence numbers. It's correct that there are 4 of them, but it just pasted the most recent sequence number 4 times instead of recording the seq number in which a 1 was present

Comment: please add a data set with various items to show where you want to group, along with the wanted result.

Comment: As an example: say
Seq:1 fq: 0
Seq:2 fq: 1
Seq:3 fq: 1

My resulting array says {Seq: "1, 1" fq: 2}. So it gets the fq right, and the number of times a seq should appear right, but its just putting the most recent seq number, not the correct ones, it should be {Seq: "2, 3", fq: 2}

Comment: hm what should i do with that?

Comment: i figured it out in a totally different way

Comment: great. has any answer helped you?